# Plyr media player doesn't show Vimeo and doesn't toggle Youtube closed captions

Tags: youtube, plyr, vimeo, captions, plyr.js

guys!
I'm trying to find a media player that could playback Youtube, Vimeo and HLS URLs. It seems Plyr player (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) is suitable, but I have some troubles with closed captions for Youtube and Vimeo videos. Although videos show captions in Youtube and Vimeo players and it is possible to toggle them, I wasn't able to load captions for Vimeo video at all and can't toggle Youtube captions using Plyr. Could you please give some examples how to solve this captions problem with Plyr? Or with another media player?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what is wrong with captions in Plyr for Vimeo videos.

Plyr.io uses Vimeo Player (https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) inside it, so it builds an iframe into our page to playback Vimeo link. This Vimeo iframe contains not only video block but also control buttons and author of the Plyr hides them with CSS trick to show only Plyr control buttons. Unfortunately, captions also get hidden with this trick. 
    So, as we can't access iframe content we can only:

- try to come up with another CSS trick to hide only Vimeo controls and
  let captions stay (but I'm not sure it is possible)
- use Plyr without captions for Vimeo
- do not use Plyr for Vimeo